# My chrome extension isn't synced

Tags: google-chrome, synchronization

I'm currently starting develop a chrome extension. But i see that it isn't synced while other extensions that i installed from webstore have been synced to my account.
Could you please show me how to make my extension sync-able. Do they have to upload their extensions to store and register with google to make them sync-able?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will only sync apps that are published to the web store. For more information on how to integrate your extension's data with sync, see this page: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html